# Windows 8.1 scroll bars: customisable?

Tags: windows-8, themes, color-theme

**What I would like: for all windows, I want to have the slider bar a different colour from the slider rail.  and visible whether or not it is being hovered over.**

So far I have only be able to configure scrollbar colours in themes to one of two modes:

1. Slider and rail are completely invisible unless hovered over. (Slider and rail are same colour as window background). When slide rail or bar are hovered over, slider becomes visible. ("Default windows themes")
2. Slider bar and slider rail are the same colour, but have a thin outline. They take their colour from the settings for button background and foreground. (Using "high contrast themes").

Am I missing something? Or do I need to install a skinning app or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, at least for desktop mode on Windows 8. You'll need to add support for custom themes though, and there's a nice tutorial at http://www.howtogeek.com/168270/how-to-install-custom-themes-and-visual-styles-in-windows/ for doing that. Once you enable support, you can find a theme that offers the slider bar with a different color from the rail. Really, from after you enable custom themes support, the sky's the limit.

Comment: Thank you, WindowBlinds worked. Unfortunately I could not find any themes for the other patches which changed scroll bar appearances.

Comment: WindowBlinds worked well! Although it worked for firefox but not IE or chrome strangely.