# Windows 8.1: how applications inherit the OS's UI controls' styles (e.g scrollbars)

Tags: windows-8, user-interface, scrollbar

This is an extensions to [a previous question of mine.](https://superuser.com/questions/699554/windows-8-scroll-bars-customisable)

At first glance, it seems that on Windows 8.1, Firefox, Chrome and IE (for example) all implement the OS UI control appearance, when it comes to scrollbars; they inherit the OS's style of the invisible scroll bars which only appear when hovered over.

I wanted to change this, hence my previous question. I had the most luck by installing WindowBlinds. However, only Firefox reflected the changes in its scrollbars; those of Chrome and IE kept the old appearance. (Yet strangely, the rest of the appearance of their windows were changed successfully.)

Why is this? Is it a bug in Windows 8.1? A bug in WindowBlinds? A quirk with the way IE and Chrome implement the OS UI scrollbar styles? Something else? And is there anything I can do about it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed if this problem existed in Windows 8.0?

Comment: I have not seen any information about this on windows 8 and do not have a copy to try it out on

Comment: Microsoft offers free virtual machines which includs one that is running Windows 8. You might have to use an older version of WindowsBlinds but it should be compatible.  A screenshot of of what your expecting and actually experieicng might be helpful.